# Passing `List` of value types to a method expecting `IEnumerable` of reference types

Tags: c#, generics, value-type, downcast, reference-type

I am wondering why it is not possible in .NET to pass in a list of value types to a method which expects an `IEnumerable` of reference types. For example,

```
void MyMethod(IEnumerable<object> items) {}
...
var dtList = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Now };
MyMethod(dtList); // not possible, but it's possible to make a cast object o = DateTime.Now;
```

As this works fine for reference types, I came to a conclusion that in the case of value types the boxing is required for **each element** in the collection and it might hit the performance, but I may be wrong and there are some other things to be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because *value types* are not covarient (they need to be boxed), and as such lose their *identity* for-which the *compiler* is instructed to preserve by the specs. But you can *cast* it `.Cast<object>()` (at the cost of boxing), which may or may not be an issue for you.

For more details about *identity* you can see Eric Lipperts blog on [Representation and identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/)

> All the built-in reference conversions are identity-preserving. This
>   is why covariant and contravariant conversions of interface and
>   delegate types require that all varying type arguments be of reference
>   types. To ensure that a variant reference conversion is always
>   identity-preserving, all of the conversions involving type arguments
>   must also be identity-preserving.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting the idea. But let me figure out covariance and contravariance a bit more and I'll get back to your answer.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand. Having `IEnumerable<object>` the compiler even wouldn't know that it has to perform boxing and could use the data in the wrong way. You know, it was really interesting to read about identity-preserving. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

We can use make use of `Cast` here:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source);
```

***Summary:*** Casts the elements of an `System.Collections.IEnumerable` to the specified type.

***Returns:*** A `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` that contains each element of the source sequence cast to the specified type.